# How to solve this generic with repository pattern problem?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, repository-pattern

I had this code from a previous question, but its not compiling:

```
    public interface IEntity
{     
// Common to all Data Objects
}
public interface ICustomer : IEntity
{
     // Specific data for a customer
}
public interface IRepository<T, TID> : IDisposable where T : IEntity
{
     T Get(TID key);
     IList<T> GetAll();
     void Save (T entity);
     T Update (T entity);
     // Common data will be added here
}
public class Repository<T, TID> : IRepository
{
     // Implementation of the generic repository
}
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
     // Specific operations for the customers repository
}
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<ICustomer>, ICustomerRepository
{
     // Implementation of the specific customers repository
}
```

But in these 2 lines :

1- public class Repository : IRepository

2- public class CustomerRepository : Repository, ICustomerRepository

It give me this error: Using the generic type 'TestApplication1.IRepository' requires '2' type arguments

can you help me solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use two type arguments when inheriting from Repository/IRepository because they take take two type arguments. Namely, when you inherit from IRepository, you need to specify something like:

```
public class Repository<T, TID> : IRepository<T,TID> where T:IEntity
```

and

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<ICustomer,int>,ICustomerRepository
```

Edited to add type constraint on implementation of Reposistory

Comment: now giving this error: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TestApplication1.IRepository<T,TID>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'TestApplication1.IEntity'.

Comment: A missed detail, sorry. Your type constraints aren't going to be inherited, so you need to specify them again. In your Repository generic class, add where T : IEntity after IRepository<T,TID>

Comment: But now i have another problem, that i can't implement GetAll function inside the CustomerRepository , how to declare it there while CustomerRepository  not inherting IReprository

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, since based on your code, it appears to be implemented in your base class, Repository<T,TID>. If you are unhappy with the base class implementation in the context of CustomerRepository, you can use public new IList<ICustomer> GetAll() to hide the original implementation.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make IList<T> GetAll() virtual in your base class, and use the override keyword in subclasses that need to behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

When you are implementing a generic interface, you need to provide the generic interface type specifications as well.  Change those two lines to:

```
public class Repository<T, TID> : IRepository<T, TID>
     where T : IEntity
{  
    // ...
```

and

```
public class CustomerRepository : Repository<ICustomer, int /*TID type*/>, ICustomerRepository
{
     // ...
```

Comment: now giving this error: The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TestApplication1.IRepository<T,TID>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'TestApplication1.IEntity'.

Comment: Sorry - I edited my answer.  You have to put the constraint for T : IEntity in Repository, as well.  I forgot to include that.